# Why react add extra string in import image name?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When import image react automatically add some extra name. How to stop it?

[image: 1]

But in browser its shows:

[image: 2]

Comment: when you run a react app a build of the application is created, this string is a key provided to the image. So, that it won't get confused with other images or assets. Why exactly do you want to remove it?

Comment: for image seo, i need exact name.